# Moving Image after Upload not Working on PHP code

Tags: php, file-upload, php-5.6

I'm having an issues with my code. I don't know what's wrong with my code because when I tested and run this to PHP version 5.4, this was working.

Then, after I transferred the files with a PHP version of 5.6, this doesn't working anymore.

Please help. I'm new to this.

Here's the code for uploading image from a form

```
if(!empty($_FILES["cover"]["name"])){

        $ext = explode(".",$_FILES["cover"]["name"]);
        $filename = substr(md5(rand(5,1000).$_FILES["cover"]["name"]),5,15).'.'.$ext[1];
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        // Check file size
        if ($_FILES["cover"]["size"] > 2621440 /*2.5mb*/) {
            echo "<script>alert('Sorry, your file is too large. Be sure to optimize the image you want to upload.');</script>";
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='.$BASE_URL.'new.php?error=file"/>';
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }


        // Allow certain file formats
        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
        && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
            echo "<script>alert('Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.');</script>";
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='.$BASE_URL.'new.php?error=file"/>';
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            echo "<script>alert('Sorry, your file was not uploaded.');</script>";
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='.$BASE_URL.'new.php?error=file"/>';
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cover"]["tmp_name"],"uploads/".$filename)) {
                echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='.$BASE_URL.'edit.php?id='.$bookid.'"/>';
            } else {
                echo "<script>alert('Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.');</script>";
                echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='.$BASE_URL.'new.php?error=file"/>';
            }
        }

    }
```

Any suggestions and comments are much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any errors displayed?

Comment: [23-Oct-2017 09:37:43 Asia/Manila] PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0

Comment: above code is working well, after i transferred the files into a latest version of PHP 5.6, the image is not moving to a folder

Comment: Please try to specify an absolute path in `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cover"]["tmp_name"], '/a/path/from/root/to/uploads/' . filename)` and make sure that the folder exists and your web server has a correct permission to write.